# How does Google know what apps I've installed if I login to gmail via browser?

Tags: gmail, google

I logged into gmail using Microsoft Edge and Google immediately sent an email saying that my device doesn't have the latest Google apps.

How did Google come to know which apps I have installed and if they are latest or an older version? It would make sense if i was using the gmail app. But in my case, I logged in using the browser.

Or is it just a generic notification because I am accessing gmail via browser and Google assumes that I don't have the latest apps?

Comment: Might be gmail on Edge versus using Chrome.  Google wants to make sure you use their products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login to Gmail is the very same you use for Play Store – so in fact Google knows it's you. The browser sends a [user-agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string, by default identifying your device (brand and model). The history of your activities in Google Play Store tell which apps you've installed in what versions *on this device.*

So yes, that would be an easy thing to do for Google. I cannot say if that's really happening (or if your guess of not using the native app triggering such message is what's done) – but it's technically possible.

Comment: Seems most appropriate than the other answers I have received. I don't like Google spying so much even when I use a browser.

Comment: That's the problem with all their products using the very same account – and what's often called "super profiling". I use Gmail only for Playstore notifications (receipts of bought apps and the occasional "security mail" when I logged in with a new device), nothing more. If someone sends me a mail from his/her Gmail account to my personal address, my mail server sends an auto-reply telling to please use a "less spying" mail provider and that I might not answer for mentioned reasons (I don't want all my communication scanned there) …

Answer (score 0):

You've most likely received the notification since you accessed a Google Service (Gmail) through a non-Google Service (Microsoft Edge).

They probably assumed you bought a new Microsoft Device and sent out a default notification to remind you to install Chrome instead of relying on their competitor's browser. This happens to me on occasion when I log in to a new device at work, usually when it's been set up out of the box and I try to sync my Google Account.